# Alternative way to extract the most recent file using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

All, I have written some code to get the latest files from a directory, the files I am looking for contain the string `sProcScript = "sProcScript"` and in the selected directory I might have several versions:

```
sProcScriptBigGuns1001.sql
sProcScriptBigGuns1007.sql
sProcScriptEdAggVal1006.sql
sProcScriptEdAggVal1007.sql
...
```

and I want to pick up the *latest version only* (the version number being the number after the file name i.e. 1007 etc.). So in the above this would be `sProcScriptBigGuns1007.sql` and `sProcScriptEdAggVal1007.sql`. To do this I wrote the following snippet (as part of a larger method), where `strPath` is the path to the relevant directory

```
DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(strPath);
List<FileInfo> listFileInfo = new List<FileInfo>();
listFileInfo = dirInfo.EnumerateFiles().ToList<FileInfo>();

// Loop in to locate special processes.
List<FileInfo> specialProcList = new List<FileInfo>();
foreach (FileInfo fi in listFileInfo)
    if (Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi.FullName).Contains(sProcScript))
        specialProcList.Add(fi);

// Get distinct.
List<string> nameList = new List<string>();
foreach (FileInfo fi in specialProcList)
{
    string strsProc = 
        Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Regex.Replace(fi.Name, @"[\d]", String.Empty));
    if (!nameList.Contains(strsProc))
        nameList.Add(strsProc);
}
List<FileInfo> tmpList;
List<string> tmpNameList = new List<string>();
tmpList = specialProcList.OrderByDescending(f => f.Name).ToList();
foreach (string name in nameList)
{
    foreach (FileInfo fi in tmpList)
    {
        if (fi.Name.Contains(name))
        {
            tmpNameList.Add(fi.Name);
            listFilesFound.Add(fi);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

which works great. However, I think there will be a much better and neater way of doing this using LINQ but I am new to LINQ and can't seem to get started with it (the attempts I have made are poor enough to not want to post them here!). **Can someone demonstate a better way of doing the above operation using LINQ?**

Thanks for your time.

Comment: This is not a code review question. I have demonstrated a viable solution to illustrate I don't want the work done for me. The question could be answered without the code snippet.

Comment: This is part of even larger method? I think writing smaller methods would make your code more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another one (assuming the filename is always *SomeCharactersSomeNumbers.extension*):

```
void Main()
{
    var sProcScript = "sProcScript";

    var fileNames = new [] {"sProcScriptBigGuns1001.sql", 
                            "sProcScriptBigGuns1007.sql",
                            "sProcScriptEdAggVal1006.sql",
                            "sProcScriptEdAggVal1007.sql"};

    var grouped = from f in fileNames
                  where f.Contains(sProcScript)
                  let m = new {FileName = f, 
                               Group = new string(f.TakeWhile(c=>!Char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray()),
                               Version = Int32.Parse(new string(f.Where(c=>Char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray()))}
                  group m by m.Group;

    var files = grouped.Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(f => f.Version).First().FileName);                    

    foreach (var file in files)
        Console.WriteLine(file);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
var selectedFileInfos = listFileInfo
    .Where(x => { 
        var filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x.FullName); 
        return specialProcList.Any(y => filename.Contains(y);})
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Name)
    .GroupBy(x => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Regex.Replace(x.Name, @"[\d]", String.Empty)) 
    .Select(x => x.First());
```

But be careful: file numbers should be padded with zeros. 0001, 0900, 0999, 1000, 1001. If they are just normally numbered with 1, 900, 999, 1000 etc., even your code will fail.

Comment: Thanks very much, however the edit to you answer was required to get it to work. The edit compiles but returns nothing - can you advise. Again, thanks very much for your time...

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
var files = from file in new DirectoryInfo(strPath).EnumerateFiles()
            let nameWithoutEx = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name)
            where nameWithoutEx.Contains(sProcScript)
            let key = new string(nameWithoutEx.Reverse()
                                              .SkipWhile(char.IsDigit)
                                              .Reverse()
                                              .ToArray())
            group file by key into versionGroup
            select versionGroup
                  .OrderBy(f => int.Parse(new string(f.Name
                                                      .Skip(versionGroup.Key.Length)
                                                      .TakeWhile(char.IsDigit)
                                                      .ToArray())))
                  .Last();
```

Comment: Thanks but as this stands it won't compile due to a number of errors. Thanks for your time...

Comment: @Killercam: Didn't try, but what are the errors? What version of C# / .NET are you on?

Comment: Framework 4.0, there were a few. I have an answer above working so I wont waste anymore of your time. But thanks you very much for your response it is most appreciated.

Comment: @Killercam: The only thing missing was the ToArray() calls. Fine now.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles(filePath)
    .Select(f => new { FileName = f, SprocName = regex.Replace(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f), ""), Version = int.Parse(regex.Match(f).Value) })
    .Where(f => f.FileName.Contains(sProcScript))
    .GroupBy(f => f.SprocName)
    .Select(g => new { Sproc = g.Key, MaxVersion = g.Max(s => s.Version) })
    .Dump();
```